# i need to get 40 boxes in django output but i am getting only 2 boxes

Tags: django

from django.shortcuts import render
import random

## Create your views here.

def home(request):
    l=[]

```
for i in str(random.randint(1,40)):
    l.append(i)


return render(request,
              'check/web.html',
              {'list':l}
              )
```

templates:

{% for i in list %}

      {{i}}


  {% endfor %}

**I am getting only two boxes instead of 40 boxes**

Answer (score 0):

Made a few changes in your code, the below should work for you.

```
import numpy as np

def home(request):
    l=[]
    for i in range(40):
        l.append(str(np.random.randint(1,40)))
    return render(request,'check/web.html',{'list':l})
```

or

```
import numpy as np

def home(request):
    l=[str(np.random.randint(1,40)) for i in range(40)]
    return render(request,'check/web.html',{'list':l})
```